# Controlling multiple buttons through a single button

Tags: vba, excel

I have created 10 different buttons and each button has a unique SUB() assigned to it. 
I now want to execute all the 10 buttons at a single click through a master button. Is that possible ? Can someone guide me?

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far, and where you are having a specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your "master" button is named after "MasterBtn" you just add its following click event handler:

```
Private Sub MasterBtn_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CommandButton" Then If ctrl.name <> "MasterBtn" Then ctrl.Value = True
    Next
End Sub
```

this approach is:

- "robust"

  in that you don't have to bother about remembering to "list" all other macro names
- "maintainable"

  in that you don't have to change this sub no matter how many buttons you may add or remove in your further coding development

Comment: Is it possible to add the sub's of different buttons into one and execute multiple subs through a single button?

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. I'd say you're asking the same functionality you already get per this OP's answer ...

Answer (score 1):

You can call your macros

```
Sub AllMAcros()
    macro1
    Macro2
    Macro3
End Sub
```

Whatever the macro names are

Answer (score 0):

Call all the sub executions from the 'master button'. You can call another sub by using the `CALL` statement.

Example:

```
Sub MasterButton()
   Call Button1
   Call Button2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also "click" on the buttons by changing its values to "True":

```
Sub clicking()

yourButtonName1.Value = True ' <- click
yourButtonName2.Value = True ' <- click
yourButtonName3.Value = True ' <- click

End Sub
```